# whats a simple way of inputting days of the week in a view?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

So I have 3 text views to show the forecast of the next 3 days. I used view binding to bind the views but I feel there's a much simpler way of writing this but I can't think of a solution. How could I iterate through the days of the week and set the text view accordingly?

```
'''
// getting day of the week
private val dayOfWeek: DayOfWeek = LocalDate.now().dayOfWeek
// getting day of week as int value
private val dayNum: Int = dayOfWeek.value
```

'''

```
     ''' // 1 = monday etc

      private fun forecastDays() {


        when (dayNum){
            // forecast of next three days
            1 -> {
                binding.tvDay1.text = "Tuesday"
                binding.tvDay2.text = "Wednesday"
                binding.tvDay3.text = "Thursday"
            }
            2 -> {
                binding.tvDay1.text = "Wednesday"
                binding.tvDay2.text = "Thursday"
                binding.tvDay3.text = "Friday"
            }
            3 -> {
                binding.tvDay1.text = "Thursday"
                binding.tvDay2.text = "Friday"
                binding.tvDay3.text = "Saturday"
            }
            4 -> {
                binding.tvDay1.text = "Friday"
                binding.tvDay2.text = "Saturday"
                binding.tvDay3.text = "Sunday"
            }
          .. etc
```

'''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably do it with `DateFormatter` i guess . Here is the one other approach with map. u can make `daysMap` as a constant.

```
val daysMap = mapOf(
    1 to "Sunday", 2 to "Monday", 3 to "Tuesday", 4 to "Wednesday", 5 to "Thursday", 6 to "Friday", 7 to "Saturday"
)
val dayOfWeek: DayOfWeek = LocalDate.now().dayOfWeek
val dayNum: Int = dayOfWeek.value
binding.tvDay1.text = daysMap[(dayNum + 1) % 7]
binding.tvDay2.text = daysMap[(dayNum + 2) % 7]
binding.tvDay3.text = daysMap[(dayNum + 3) % 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

[DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#MONDAY) is an [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), which means that you can use the ordinal as an index to fetch DayOfWeek numerically.

```
// getting day of the week
private val dayOfWeek: DayOfWeek = LocalDate.now().dayOfWeek
// ordinal
private val dayNum: Int = dayOfWeek.ordinal()
...
private fun forecastDays() {

    binding.tvDay1.text = DayOfWeek.values()[(dayNum + 1) % 7].name()
    binding.tvDay2.text = DayOfWeek.values()[(dayNum + 2) % 7].name()
    binding.tvDay3.text = DayOfWeek.values()[(dayNum + 3) % 7].name()
...
```